# How to scale data proportionality as to equal 100%

Tags: arithmetic

I am applying for a grant for the nonprofit I run, and I have some data they need for the grant. However, this data does not equal to 100% and I need to know how to scale the data up so that it is still representative of the results, but added together equals 100%.

This is the data I found:

group 1: 7.2

group 2: 5.5

group 3: 5.3

group 4: 5.5

group 5: 4.1

I need to know how to scale these up so that I can represent them as part of 100%. Additional information; the total number of participants is 4,515

Comment: I do not understand your question, but for any given variable, you can always scale it so that it adds up 100 by simply dividing the variable by the sum of all the observations and multiplying by 100.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a pretty simple way to do it, thanks!